# Blazor attach function call to EventCallBack

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor function that is

```
public async Task DoSomething()
```

I have another class object like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public EventCallback OnClick {get;set;}
}
```

This class object is consumed by blazor components. What I would like to do is to attach the DoSomething() event to the EventBackkBack OnClick in the class object. I tried this:

```
_collection.Add(new SomeClass{ Title = "some title", Icon = "icon", OnClick = DoSomething});
```

This does not work as the compiler is saying cannot convert to method group to non-delegate type EventCallBack ...

I can make it work if I change the property OnClick to "Action", but that requires the function call to be "async void". I cannot do that for other reasons.

Is there a way for me to attach this async Task function to OnClick? Thanks!

Comment: What you mean, I upvoted one just two days ago ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got this the wrong way round: `EventCallBack` is what you expose as a bindable property on a Razor component, not normally a property on a class.

Chris Sainty shows how this works in this article: https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/

In the first example his component has a bindable property

```
[Parameter] public EventCallback<string> OnClick { get; set; }
```

This tells someone using the component that it will send an event with a string parameter. This can be bound to a method, which he shows next:

```
<ChildComponent OnClick="ClickHandler"></ChildComponent>

<p>@message</p>

@code {

    string message = "Hello from ParentComponent";

    void ClickHandler(string newMessage)
    {
        message = newMessage;
    }

}
```

Note that the bound method, `ClickHandler` is not async. Blazor supports both async and sync calls, it could also be

```
    async Task ClickHandler(string newMessage)
    {
        message = await SomeAsyncMethod(newMessage);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will give it a shot!

Comment: In case you want to attach in code and not in markup, you have to [use something like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.eventcallbackfactory.create) `MyComponentRef.OnClick = EventCallback.Factory.Create<string>(this, ClickHandler)`.

Comment: @UweKeim thank you, I needed this. I am dynamically rendering a component that has an EventCallback. Without the EventCallback.Factory, I couldn't get the parameter to work correctly.